# LINQ Exception if node don't exists

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to read a xml file and write it to entities in data model. 
The Xml looks like this :

```
...
<item>
   <guid>123456-7890</guid>
   <enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="http://example.com"/>
</item>
```

Sometimes whole enclosure node doesn't exists, so I'm using let in my query, but it breaks:

```
var items = from xmlitems in xElem2.Descendants("item")
            let node_enclosure = xmlitems.Element("enclosure")
            select new
            {
                 strImageUrl = node_enclosure == null ? "none" : node_enclosure.Attribute("url").Value,
                 strguid = xmlitems.Element("guid").Value,
            };
```

Update: Then I'm trying to save value from xml in Datacontext.

```
using (var datacontext = new db_RBEntities1())
{
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
         try
         {                 
              xmltable = new RSSTable();
              xmltable.guid = item.guid;
              xmltable.imageurl= item.strImageUrl;            
              datacontext.RSSTable.AddObject(xmltable);
         }
         catch (EntitySqlException ex)
         {
         }
     }
     datacontext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Could you help me what's wrong with my query?
Thanks for your advices!

Regards

Comment: So you do you or do you not want to have that exception to occur?

Comment: I think Eric Lippert [foresaw](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/08/14/out-parameters-and-linq-do-not-mix.aspx) this one...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query, it works either way - what problem are you seeing?

Comment: Jeff and brokenglass: it isn't inserted in datacontext if enclosure node doesnt't exists, so it should insert default value. Chrisstoffer, Thanks for link

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted the question, but I'm thinking that one possible reason for the downvote is that you've posted code that's badly formatted (way to much indentation) and not compiling (missing end braces, etc.) without some effort from who ever is trying to help you. When you post your next question, you might want to think about that, @nukleos. Cheers.

Comment: sorry for this, reformatted my code. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what problem you're having with your code but you can rewrite it to be a little nicer looking (IMHO).

If there's a possibility that an element may or may not exist in your document and you want to get something from that element, I find it easier to query all elements by that name (expecting there's only one), project to the value you want (in this case, the value of the `url` attribute) and call `SingleOrDefault()`.  This way, you'll either get your value or the default value (`null` in this case).

Also, use casts to read your values from elements or attributes, this makes it less likely to get a `NullPointerException` when trying to read values.

```
var items =
    from item in doc.Descendants("item")
    let enclosureUrl = item.Elements("enclosure")
        .Select(enclosure => (string)enclosure.Attribute("url"))
        .SingleOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        Guid = (string)item.Element("guid"),
        Url = enclosureUrl ?? "none",
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

i try it works
xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<items>
  <item>
    <guid>123458-7890</guid>    
  </item>
  <item>
    <guid>123456-7890</guid>
    <enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="http://example.com"/>
  </item>
</items>
```

code to get xelement

```
XElement xElem2 = XElement.Load(@"C:\\XMLFile1.xml");
              var items = from xmlitems in xElem2.Descendants("item")
                          let node_enclosure = xmlitems.Element("enclosure")
                          select new
                          {
                              strImageUrl = node_enclosure == null ? "none" : node_enclosure.Attribute("url").Value,
                              strguid = xmlitems.Element("guid").Value
                          };
```